# Should I use useQuery twice in siblings or once from parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

Imagine I have a component called Parent and two child components called ChildA and ChildB. In both of those components I need access to a specific remote resource. I figure I have two options:

1. Call `useQuery` once in the parent then pass the output down to the children as props.
2. Call `useQuery` twice, one in each child.

My understand is `useQuery` does some kind of caching so it won't actually fetch twice. Assuming that is true, which of these two options would be considered more idiomatic for react-query and hooks in general, and why?

Comment: The answer is... it depends. If you're going to fetch exactly the same data, I'd suggest using `useQuery` on the parent component and simply providing the fetched data via a context provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Assuming that is true, which of these two options would be considered
> more idiomatic for react-query and hooks in general, and why?

It is also my understanding that the `useQuery` hook memoizes/caches results per query/parameter. The second method where each component individually calls the hook and receives the memoized/cached data is optimal since it completely decouples one component from the another.

It's sort of the same reason we use React contexts to avoid needing to drill props through to the components that actually care.